# How to use swig to wrap classes with the same name in multiple namespaces using the "using" keyword

Tags: python, c++, swig

It is already known that such a problem occurs when using swig to convert cpp to python. The tempA type is defined in the namespace a::b::c in cpp, and then I use it in in another namespace.

```
namespace d {
namespace b {
     namespace xx = a::b::c;
     using tempA = xx::tempA;
} 
}
```

there is also a namespace e

```
namespace e 
{
     using tempA = d::b::tempA;
}
```

These are defined in their respective tempa.hpp,a/temA.hpp d/tempA.hpp e/tempA.hpp
I also want to override some methods of tempA(important!)like this

```
%{
#include "a/tempA.hpp"
%}

// SWIG does not support templates in the generated binding,
// because not all output languages support them
// We must explicitly declare the specializations of the templates
%template(TempAPtr) std::shared_ptr<a::b::c::TempA>;

// Ignore overloaded method that has no application in python
// Otherwise it will issue a warning
%ignore a::b::c::TempA::TempA(TempA &&);

// This constructor takes ownership of the xxx pointer
// We need SWIG to be aware of it, so we ignore it here and redefine it later
%ignore a::b::c::TempA::TempA(a::b::c::xxx*);


%include "a/TempA.hpp"

// To make SWIG aware of the loss of the ownership, use the DISOWN typemap
// Do not worry about the heap allocation, SWIG recognizes the method as a constructor
// and successfully deallocates on destruction
%extend a::b::c::TempA {
    %apply SWIGTYPE *DISOWN { a::b::c::xxx* ptr };
    TempA(a::b::c::xxx* ptr)
    {
        return new a::b::c::TempA(ptr);
    }

    %apply SWIGTYPE *DISOWN { a::b::c::xxx* ptr };
    void set(a::b::c::xxx* ptr)
    {
        self->reset(ptr);
    }

}
```

How to write tempA.i of them ,How to write it in the overall module.i file. The purpose of implementation is to expose e::tempA to be mapped to Python instead of a: :b::c::tempA,